# ArrayList and Passing values

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, jcreator

I am new to programming and we just learned ArrayLists in my class today and I have an easy question for you guys, I just can't seem to find it in the notes on what to set the passing value equal to. The point of this practice program is to take in a Number Object (that class has already been created) and those Numbers in the ArrayList are supposed to be counted as odds, evens, and perfect numbers. Here is the first couple of lines of the program which is all you should need.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class NumberAnalyzer {

    private ArrayList<Number> list;

    public NumberAnalyzer() {
        list = new ArrayList<Number>();
    }

    public NumberAnalyzer(String numbers) {

    }

    public void setList(String numbers) {

    }
```

What am I supposed to set (String numbers) to in both NumberAnalyzer() and setList()? Thanks in advance for answering a noob question!

```
    NumberAnalyzer test = new NumberAnalyzer("5 12 9 6 1 4 8 6");
    out.println(test);
    out.println("odd count = "+test.countOdds());
    out.println("even count = "+test.countEvens());
    out.println("perfect count = "+test.countPerfects()+"\n\n\n");
```

This is the Lab16b Class that will run the program. ^^

```
public class Number
{
private Integer number;
public Number()
{
    number = 0;
}
public Number(int num)
{
    number = num;
}
public void setNumber(int num)
{
    number = num;
}
public int getNumber()
{
    return 0;
}
public boolean isOdd()
{
    return number % 2 != 0;
}
public boolean isPerfect()
{
    int total=0;
    for(int i = 1; i < number; i++)
    {
        if(number % i == 0)
        {
            total = total + i;
        }
    }
    if(total == number)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public String toString( )
{
    return "";
}
}
```

Here is the Number class. ^^

Comment: What does the `String numbers` look like? Is it a string containing objects separated by spaces?

Comment: String numbers is the value I am trying to pass. It has only been initialized.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Where have you initialized it? Does the `string` being passed to look something like "1 3 2 5 4 9"?

Comment: My bad. I forgot to mention the Lab16b class in which the teacher will enter in random numbers into a String such as "5 17 18 20 87" and then he will run the program. That is where the String numbers comes in

Comment: Please give an example of your input. I can't understand your task at all. Please exemplify inputs, outputs, behaviors.

Comment: So you've been given the assignment of filling in the code for the `NumberAnalyzer` constructor and `setList()` (although `setList()` doesn't seem to be called from the test harness code).  To ask a question on StackOverflow you are expected to attempt the solution, run it, and when you encounter a problem ask a _specific_ question showing what you've done and any unexpected behavior or error messages.  As it reads right now this is almost a "write my code for me" question, which is off-topic.

Comment: To answer your specific question, you don't have to set the input parameter `numbers`. Its value is being provided by the test code and you have to parse it and count the odds, evens and perfect numbers.  If you have no idea where to start you should be talking to your professor as that should have been covered in the lecture.

Comment: Well if it has to be like that, I have attempted to set String numbers to every possible value in this program and none of it works.

Comment: @user2948668 When you say "it does not work", you address a problem. In order to get help, according to the rules of SO, you need to make an effort understanding your problem. You have to describe your problem in your question, with expected and actual results, error messages, etc. Just asking someone to write your code for you is not for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, this is what I feel `NumberAnalyzer` should look like. The `setList` function is presently being used to take a `String` and add the numbers in it to a new list.

```
public class NumberAnalyzer {

    private List<Number> list;

    public NumberAnalyzer() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<Number>();
    }

    public NumberAnalyzer(String numbers) {
        setList(numbers);
    }

    public void setList(String numbers) {
        String[] nums = numbers.split(" ");
        this.list = new ArrayList<Number>();
        for(String num: nums) 
            list.add(new Number(Integer.parseInt(num)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Analyze to learn something.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String temp = "5 12 9 6 1 4 8 6";
    NumberAnalyzer analyzer = new NumberAnalyzer(temp);

    //foreach without lambda expressions
    System.out.println("without Lambda");
    for (NeverNumber i : analyzer.getList()) {
        i.print();
    }
    //with the use of lambda expressions, which was introduced in Java 8
    System.out.println("\nwith Lambda");
    analyzer.getList().stream().forEach((noNumber) -> noNumber.print());

    NeverNumber number = new NeverNumber(31);
    number.print();
    number.setNumber(1234);
    number.print();

}

public class NumberAnalyzer {

    private List<NeverNumber> list; //List is interface for ArrayList

    public NumberAnalyzer(String numbers) {
        String[] numb=numbers.split(" ");
        this.list=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String i : numb) {
            list.add(new NeverNumber(Integer.parseInt(i)));
        }
    }

    public void setList(List<NeverNumber> numbers) {
        List<NeverNumber> copy=new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.stream().forEach((i) -> {
            copy.add(i.copy());
        });
        this.list=copy;
    }

    public List<NeverNumber> getList() {
        List<NeverNumber> copy=new ArrayList<>();
        this.list.stream().forEach((i) -> {
            copy.add(i.copy());
        });
        return copy;
    }

    public NeverNumber getNumber(int index) {
        return list.get(index).copy();
    }

}

public class NeverNumber { //We do not use the names used in the standard library.
    //In the library there is a class Number.

    private int number; // If you can use simple types int instead of Integer.

    public NeverNumber() {
        number = 0;
    }

    public NeverNumber(int num) {
        number = num;
    }

    private NeverNumber(NeverNumber nn) {
        this.number=nn.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int num) {
        number = num;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public boolean isOdd() {
        return number % 2 != 0;
    }

    public boolean isPerfect() {
        long end = Math.round(Math.sqrt(number)); //Method Math.sqrt(Number) returns a double, a method Math.round(double) returns long.
        for (int i = 2; i < end + 1; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public NeverNumber copy(){
        return new NeverNumber(this);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("for: " + this.toString() + " isPer: " + this.isPerfect() + " isOdd: " + this.isOdd() + "\n");
    }

    @Override //Every class in Java inherits from the Object class in which it is toString(), 
    //so we have to override our implementation.
    public String toString() {
        return this.number + "";  //The object of any class + "" creates a new object of the String class, 
        //that is for complex types, calls the toString () method implemented in this class, 
        //override the toString () from the Object class. If the runs, we miss class toString() 
        //calls from the Object class.
    }

}
```